# Handlebars.js: index access to global.json from a loop

Tags: json, handlebars.js

I have a global.json file:

```
{
    "title": "problem",
    "dict": [
        {
            "name": "A",
            "similar": [1, 2]
        },
        {
            "name": "B",
            "similar": [0]
        },
        {
            "name": "C",
            "similar": [1]
        },
     ]
}
```

and I want the following result for `A` as an example:

```
A
B C
```

I tried to use the following handlebars script:

```
{{#with global.dict.[0]}}

{{name}}

{{#each similar}}
   {{@root.global.dict.[this].name}}
{{/each}}
{{/with}}
```

The output is is just `A`. However, it seems `this` is not recognized as integer here to used as the index

Comment: Are the values at each `similar` property intended to be indexes within `dict`? If so, shouldn't it be, for example, [1, 2] instead of [2, 3] - ie., shouldn't these be 0-indexed?

Comment: @76484, you are right. fixed the indices in the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use the lookup helper to [lookup](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/builtin-helpers.html#lookup) the dynamic `this` index on `@root.global.dict`. You would then have to do a second lookup to get the `name` property of the result. Alternatively, you could use the [with](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/builtin-helpers.html#with) helper to give you a block scoped to the result of the first lookup, as in:

```
{{#each similar}}
    {{#with (lookup @root.global.dict this)}}
        {{name}}
    {{/with}}
{{/each}}
```

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/7ako49hy/) for your reference.