# How to get index value of array in handlebar template

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

```
function getFruitsData()
{
var fruit=[];
fruit.push("Apple");
fruit.push("Mango");
fruit.push("Grapes");
fruit.push("Orange");

return fruit;
}
```

the fruits data i am sending to template 
which is coming in console

[image]

Now i need to show like this Fruits[0] which will result >>> Apple

right Now in template i using this which is not working

```
{{#each someOtherList}}

{{this.[Fruits].@index.this}} >> not working
{{Fruits.@index.this}} >> not working
{{Fruits.[@index]}} >> not working

{{/each}}
```

i don't need to iterate all data i just need specific data according to index i pass

Comment: Use the built-in `lookup` helper. https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/builtin-helpers.html#lookup I have answered a few questions that are very similar. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54274111/3397771 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/61775752/3397771

Comment: Did  not get how to use i am new in handlebar  can you help me with reference to above example

Comment: Got the answer {{lookup ../Fruits @index}}

Comment: Thank you for the hint